# How to disable ray for debugging

Tags: pycharm, ray

In my code I am using ray to manage multiple workers, but I've realised that even if I set the number of workers to 1 I still cannot use PyCharm to debug my code (this seems to be a known issue). What I would really like to be able to do is run the code in "debug mode", say, where I don't use ray at all. Currently all my workers are initialised with something like:

```
@ray.remote(num_gpus=0.25)
def worker_function():
    ...
```

and called from a main script with something like `worker_function.remote()`. So I guess I would like to somehow make the @ray.remote(...) optional. Is there a nice way to do something like this?

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 possible ways to do this.

1. Initialize Ray in [local mode](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/ray-core/starting-ray.html#local-mode). This will make all ray tasks and actors run serially in a single process allowing you to use your native debugger. Note that since your program is now serialized, it could behave in a subtly different way. Local mode is enabled in `ray.init(local_mode=True)`
2. If you're not tied to the pycharm debugger, Ray also provides a fairly large subset of pdb behavior on a real cluster via its own [Ray Debugger](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/ray-observability/ray-debugging.html#ray-debugger).

You could do

```
@ray.remote(num_gpus=0.25)
def worker_function():
    breakpoint()
    ...
```

to set a breakpoint in a remote function, then run the program via `ray debug` on the command line.

Comment: Thanks for this. I am keen to stick with Pycharm, but using local_mode could well be the solution. The workaround I had implemented before was just defining a separate function 
`@ray_remote(num_gpus=0.25) def worker_function_ray(): worker_function(use_ray=True)`

and then have worker_function runnable without ray.

Answer (score 1):

Hi @Henry Charlesworth!

I got the same situation while debugging different ray workers on PyCharm while trying to understand the https://github.com/YeWR/EfficientZero source code.

The EfficientZero algorithm launches several workers for different kinds of work loads (e.g. self-playing the atari game, implementing the replay buffer, reanalyzing experiences, etc...).

This is what I did to debug, for example, 2 of the different workers (in this example, the self-play worker and the replay buffer worker):

1. Use pip for installing pydevd-pycharm into your project (the version at the time of writing this message was 221.5591.52)

```
pip install pydevd-pycharm~=221.5591.52
```

2. Create a `Remote Debug Server` configuration for the self-play worker.
   [image]
3. Adapt the code of the self-play worker to connect to the new configuration on creation
   [image]
4. Create another `Remote Debug Server` configuration for the replay buffer worker.
   [image]
5. Adapt the code of the replay buffer worker to connect to the new configuration on creation
   [image]

These are all the changes that you need to add to the code.

Now, you just need to start all the configurations in the right order:

1. the remote debugger for the self-play worker
2. the remote debugger for the replay buffer worker
3. the main program

After doing this, you should see 3 tabs on the Debug section of Pycharm:

[image]

Now, by selecting any of those tabs, you could debug the 3 processes at the same time... for example, you can hit a breakpoint on the replay buffer worker...
[image]
while at the same time you are hitting another breakpoint on the self play worker...
[image]

And that's all... I hope that this can be as helpful to you as it was for me.

Best regards,

David

Comment: Thanks for this, it's super useful! (also interestingly the exact same use case I have - looking at the EfficientZero code).

Comment: jajajajajaja.
What a coincidence! :) 

I'm glad this was useful to you.

Best regards.

Comment: And here I am looking at the SAME code base wanting to do the same thing! Thank you @duxtinto!

Comment: you are welcome Jarym! :)